# Lightbox/Fancybox for Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, lightbox, fancybox-2

I installed a Fancybox2 gem in my rails app, but it's not working 100% of the time. It seems to be an issue with Turbolinks, as it only works after a refresh, or when a page is visited directly.

I already have my jquery set up using:

```
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

where `"ready"` is a function, to ensure it works around the Rails 4 turbolinks implementation, but it seems Fancybox has not been updated similarly.

Anyone find any fixes or alternatives out there to get a lightbox working nicely within Rails 4?

I'm thinking there also might be something built into fancybox that I can inside my `ready` function to re-initialize when a page loads with turbolinks?

Comment: ya seems like, issue is with turbolinks, so u can use `fancybox-rails` instead.

Comment: I was using [Fancybox2-rails](https://github.com/kyparn/fancybox2-rails)

I think I tried Fancybox-rails and had other problems... I could try again

Comment: Same problem with fancybox-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update – I've gone with [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), a free framework which works well with rails and includes a modal, as well as many other features

Answer (score 1):

It's usually an issue with Turboliknks.

To work around this I just reinitialize lightbox everytime turbolinks reloads the page.

Sample in CoffeeScript:

```
ready = () ->
  lightbox.init()

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ready
```

Comment: with this code the #lightbox div appears at the bottom of the document after using the browser back button to come back to the page (removing #lightbox and #lightboxOverlay before init() fixes it)